# Ajax javascript data appendTo ....remove last

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I was wondering if I could do a javascript `appendTo` but removing hiding my last tables before the append. Here is the code:

```
  beforeSend: function() {
  $("#divAjax").hide(); 
  },                
  success : function(data){ 
  $("#divAjax").show();
  $(data).appendTo("#divAjax");
```

Can I remove my last table and then `appendTo` my data?

Comment: Please provide a sample data that you are appending to #divAjax. Is it a pure text data or an html formatted string?

Comment: The issue is that is the same div with php so basically on load it will display new data....there really isn't need to appendTo but I saw that if I appendTo then I have the last data at the bottom so I wanted to hide that...

Comment: If it is an html string, you can specifically select the last data and hide it. But, if it is a raw text, you have no choice but to empty your `<div>` before appending. You can try to use `$("#divAjax").empty()`

Comment: That empty emptied my current div so I guess I am close to emptying my last div

Comment: So, your last data wasn't in the `#divAjax` div? Please post you dom structure so it will be more clearer.

Answer (score 3):

Just use:

```
$("#divAjax").html(data);
```

to overwrite the old content with the new

Comment: no I tried that it will display a new window that is why

Comment: the only reason I can conceive that the above will open a new window  is if `data` contains a script to make it do so